# ProgressBar doesn't display progress gradually on splashscreen

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have a splashscreen which lasts 5 seconds, and I want to represent the progress using a `ProgressBar`.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long SPLASHTIME = 5000;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        SplashHandler handlerSplash = new SplashHandler();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progression);
        progressBar.setMax((int) ((SPLASHTIME) / 1000));
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 0;
        handlerSplash.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);


        ThreadProgressBar threadProgress = new ThreadProgressBar();
        threadProgress.start();


    }

    private class ThreadProgressBar extends Thread {
        ProgressBarHandler handlerProgress = new ProgressBarHandler();
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (progressBar.getProgress() <= progressBar.getMax()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    handlerProgress.sendMessage(handlerProgress.obtainMessage());
                }
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }

        private class ProgressBarHandler extends Handler {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                progressBar
                        .incrementProgressBy((int) (SPLASHTIME / SPLASHTIME));
            }
        }

        private class SplashHandler extends Handler {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                default:
                case 0:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    // new ProgressBarIncrease().execute();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(SplashActivity.this, RdvTab.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe how this flow should work? When `SplashHandler` receives a message then it starts an `AsyncTask` to run on background which would send progress to the `ProgressBar`, then it starts a `SplashActivity` right? That logic doesn't seem clear to me

Comment: @romy_ngo I have an activity that acts as a splashactivity.
It lasts 5 seconds and then redirects to another activity thanks to a handler
I added a progress bar to show the loading time (5 seconds) I filled it in a asynchtask.
But I don't know howto fill  the progressBar gradually, it fills that at the end of splashscreen. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I guess since `SplashActivity` itself is an activity, it is ok to block UI right? `AsyncTask` sometimes run not gradually, if you want the update to be displayed smoothly, how about changing to worker `Thread` and `Handlder`.

- Create `Handler` `inside SplashActivity`
- In the main Thread, display progressBar or splash or whatever you like
- While make another Thread to run the countdown, once in every second `sendEmptyMessage()` to `Handler`. After 5 seconds, send a message to `Handler` to dismiss dialog and splash then the worker `Thread` ends.

UPDATED: Sorry for the slow feedback. How about this? I haven't tested it yet and it's not the best implementation though, you can use this logic

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASHTIME = 5000;
    // u can change the value here for smoother effect
    private static final long UPDATEINTERVAL = 1000;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progression);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                 int progress = 0;
                 while(true){
                     // send current progress to handler
                     mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(progress);
                     // break from the loop after SPLASHSCREEN millis
                     if(progress > SPLASHSCREEN)
                         break;
                     // increase the progress
                     progress = (int) (progress + UPDATEINTERVAL);
                     // sleep the worker thread
                     Thread.sleep(UPDATEINTERVAL);
                 }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message message){
             // get the current progress
             int progress = message.what;
             if(progress <= SPLASHTIME){
                 progressBar.setProgress(progress);
             }
             else{
                 // finish splashActivity here & do what u want do to after splashscreen, for example
                 finish();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(SpashActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i follow your advices and now it works , but i don ' t know if it 's clean :p. I will update my code , can you tell me please if  is a good way to proceed ? Thanks

Comment: It's good, worker Thread thread and handler will show progress smoothly. If you are not sure, feel free to post it, I will check it out for u

Answer (score 0):

You should divide the splash screen time into equal amounts and send the progress update at those intervals.

For example:Lets say the total time is divided into 50 equal intervals as follows

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
         progressbarStep = progressbarWidth/50;
         timeStep = 5000/50;
         progress = 0;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            while(progress < progressbarWidth){
                progress += progressbarStep;
                publishProgress(progress);
                SystemClock.sleep(timeStep);
               }
               return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
         progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I will rather choose the method of handler+ threads